# VBA 1004 error pulling data from other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Bit of a strange Object/User Defined 1004 error that I'm having.. maybe I'm just overlooking something.

I'm looking to implement a code very similar to one that I have used on another sheet. Essentially the sheet is a dashboard, the only cell used by the user is "b1" in the activesheet as this allows the user to choose from a dropdown menu of choices. Upon the change the information should reference ClientDB sheet to find the correct row, then pull the information from it.

Ive used very similar code previously with no hitch.. Just wondering if there is something I may be overlooking?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim DBWS As Worksheet, cws As Worksheet, sws As Worksheet
Dim aa As Integer, bb As Integer, cc As Integer, dd As Integer

Set DBWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ClientDB")
Set cws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ClientBoard")

aa = DBWS.Columns("a").Find(what:=cws.Range("b1").Value, after:=DBWS.Range("a1")).Row
bb = Range("a" & aa).Row


'contact
Range("b3").Value = DBWS.Cells(bb, "H").Value
'number
Range("b4").Value = DBWS.Cells(bb, "I").Value
'email

Range("b5").Value = DBWS.Cells(bb, "J").Value
```

'etc.. etc.. etc..

Extra Note: If I run an Error Handler to bypass the 1004 error it will eventually populate after a few errorhandler cycles

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Jay

Comment: i would advise to modify to `Dim As Long, bb As Long` just to be sure, not necessarily to resolve this issue

Comment: I am getting the error on the line: aa = DBWS.Columns("a").Find(what:=cws.Range("b1").Value, after:=DBWS.Range("a1")).Row

Answer (score 1):

Consider `DBWS.Columns("a")...` change to `DBWS.Columns("a:a")...`

`a`is not a valid reference.

Answer (score 1):

As @SickDimesion mentioned, you have to change `Columns("a")` to `DBWS.Columns("a:a")` or to `DBWS.Columns(1)`

After doing that change, you **may** still get an error because, you are directly trying to get the row. What if the `.Find` didn't return a match?

Consider changing your code to this

```
Dim aCell as Range

set aCell = DBWS.Columns(1).Find(what:=cws.Range("b1").Value, _
                                 after:=DBWS.Range("a1"))

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    aa = aCell.Row
Else
    Msgbox "Value Not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not qualifying the context for

```
bb = Range("a" & aa).Row
```

Excel does not know which sheet this Range refers to. Same for the other unqualified Range statements.

Comment: maybe I'm tired today, but what is the point of using the `bb = Range("a" & aa).Row` ?  if `aa = DBWS.Columns("a").Find(what:=cws.Range("b1").Value, after:=DBWS.Range("a1")).Row` returns a row number, and then he is putting it inside a range in order to get the row number, in this case isn't it `bb = aa` ?

Comment: Very possible sloppy coding on my part..

With your Proposed change Teylyn I have the following: 'Automation error - The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients'